# :invalid не срабатывал при загрузке страницы, а только после изменения input

Tags: css

В данном примере если "выполнить код" `input` будет красным, сработал `:invalid`, надо, чтобы `input` был со стилями по умолчанию, пока его не трогают.

Мне надо добиться такого поведения:

`input` со стилями по умолчанию, вводишь невалидное значение, убираешь `focus` и `input` становится красным только после этого.

Можно ли добиться такого поведения без использования `js`

Но в данный момент `input` краснеет при загрузке страницы. Как это исправить? Убрать `required` нельзя.

```css
input:invalid {
    background: red;
}
input:focus {
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" required/>
```

Comment: Как один из вариантов - установить фокус при загрузке страницы на это поле, если это возможно, если нет, тогда надо поразмыслить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function() {

  if (document.querySelector('input').value !== '') {
    document.querySelector('input').classList.add('active');
    console.log(document.querySelector('input'))
  } else {
    document.querySelector('input').classList.remove('active');
    console.log(document.querySelector('input'));
  }
})
```

```css
input.active:invalid {
  background: red;
}

input.active:focus {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" required/>
```

Comment: Посмотрите, если "выполнить код" в моем примере, появится красный инпут. В приведенных ответах он тоже красный. Мне надо, чтобы, когда "выполняешь код" input был по дефолту, вводишь невалидное значение, и когда убрал фокус, input стал красным. Можно ли такое сделать на чистом css?

Comment: Честно?  На чистом `css`, щас даже не соображу как....

Comment: Да в том то и дело ) Я сам не могу сообразить. На js все понятно, можно добавить нужные стили. А вот можно ли сделать проще? Вопрос

Comment: Эх... я подожду еще немного, если не найдется ответа на чистом css, то приму Ваш ответ

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать placeholder и псевдокласс `:placeholder-shown`. Минусы: поддержка браузерами, обязательный placeholder(пусть даже из пробела)

```css
input:not(:placeholder-shown):invalid {
    background: red;
}
input:focus {
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" placeholder=" " required/>
<input type="tel" placeholder="Например числа"  pattern="[^A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё]+$" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
input:not(:focus):not(:placeholder-shown):invalid {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder=" " type="email" required/>
```

Comment: Я не могу убрать `required`, я писал об этом в вопросе.

Comment: Как вариант поставить value="test@mail.ru" ?

Comment: Тоже не могу. `input` должен быть чистым!

Comment: плейсхолдер допускается? Можно выбрать инпут у которого нету плейсхолдера(что то написано)